# Using regex in QTP to match diff URL

Tags: regex, qtp

I am running same QTP script in QA and Staging environment. One test case requires me to click on a PDF document which opens in a new window. My situation is that the even though the document is the same the domain name is different. What do I do to match it. Can I use regular expression to do it?

URL of document in QA:

```
http://qaapp2/InfoLibrary/ViewDocument\.aspx\?documentid=81b60525-9393-45ac-9c89-2fb1b0cb4701&documentname=ICD10\+physician\+readiness\+survey\.pdf"
```

URL of document in Staging:

```
http://stgapp2:81/InfoLibrary/ViewDocument\.aspx\?documentid=81b60525-9393-45ac-9c89-2fb1b0cb4701&documentname=ICD10\+physician\+readiness\+survey\.pdf"
```

If you look at the URL, you would notice that everything is the same except the domain name

```
QA: qaapp2 
STG: stgapp2:81
```

Only common string sequence is 'app2'

I am unable to successfully match the using regex, I used this

```
[(stg)|(qa)][app2]
```

and it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regular expression to

```
((stg)|(qa))app2
```

I use below site to verify my regex pattern.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscriptexample.html

Note: Works only in IE as it is VBScript.